# Reading in a file in io programming language

Tags: iolanguage

I'm looking to read in a simple text file using the [IO language](http://iolanguage.org/) and print it to the screen,
so far I have:

```
f := File with("test.txt")
f openForReading
```

but just have no idea how to print it or clone the contents to an object. If anyone knows anything or could point me in a good direction it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the [docs](http://iolanguage.org/scm/io/docs/reference/index.html#/Core/Core/File)? `asBuffer` and `readLine[s]` looks just like what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it's very simple, just `f contents`. For any future reference to check for already existing methods for an object in io you can use protos, e.g. `f protos`

Answer (score 1):

From the `io>` interactive shell, have you tried?

```
f print
```

or

```
doString(f)
```

See this [blog](http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/io_language_prototype)

Comment: Yeah i got it eventually, turns out it's simply f contents. For future reference in case anyone reads this to get pre-set methods of an object simply type "File protos" or "[Object] protos" worked for me.

Comment: f contents. I did see this in some of the code samples, but I didn't understand its meaning. Please post your solution as your own answer and accept it. You're the one who found it. You're the one who should be credited for it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `readLine` to read one line to a string, and `println` to print.

```
f := File with(fileName)
f openForReading

l := f readLine
l println
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a File object with your specified path:

```
fileName := "yourFileName.txt"
file := File with(fileName)
```

Open and read the file into a variable

```
file open
fileText := file readToEnd
```

Then close the file.

```
file close
```

You should then have the 'fileText' variable available for use.